# Can any one help me pass in data in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am newbie in Swift development. I need help to pass in data when the annotation view is clicked. When annotation view is clicked it goes to a view controller called `DetailsViewController`, but not data is being passed. Can anyone help me solve this by passing in some data/details in my view controller. Thank you for the help. PS: I learn from other developers code. :-).

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

protocol UserLocationDelegate {
  func userLocation(latitude :Double, longitude :Double)
}

class NearMeMapViewController: ARViewController, ARDataSource, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  var nearMeIndexSelected = NearMeIndexTitle ()
  var locationManager : CLLocationManager!
  var nearMeARAnnotations = [ARAnnotation]()


  var nearMeRequests = [NearMeRequest]()
  var delegate : UserLocationDelegate!



  var place: Place?



  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.title = nearMeIndexSelected.indexTitle


    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager ()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    self.dataSource = self
    self.headingSmoothingFactor = 0.05
    self.maxVisibleAnnotations = 30

    getNearMeIndexSelectedLocation()



  }

  func getNearMeIndexSelectedLocation()

    {

    let nearMeRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    nearMeRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = nearMeIndexSelected.indexTitle
    let nearMeregion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.locationManager.location!.coordinate, 250, 250)
    nearMeRequest.region = nearMeregion
    let nearMeSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: nearMeRequest)
    nearMeSearch.start { (response : MKLocalSearchResponse?, error :Error?) in

      for requestItem in (response?.mapItems)! {

        let nearMeIndexRequest = NearMeRequest ()
        nearMeIndexRequest.name = requestItem.name
        nearMeIndexRequest.coordinate = requestItem.placemark.coordinate
        nearMeIndexRequest.address = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"] as! [String]
        nearMeIndexRequest.street = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["Street"] as! String!
        nearMeIndexRequest.city = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["City"] as! String
        nearMeIndexRequest.state = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["State"] as! String
        nearMeIndexRequest.zip = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["ZIP"] as! String

        self.nearMeRequests.append(nearMeIndexRequest)
        print(requestItem.placemark.name)

      }

      for nearMe in self.nearMeRequests {


        let annotation = NearMeAnnotation(nearMeRequest: nearMe)

        self.nearMeARAnnotations.append(annotation)
        self.setAnnotations(self.nearMeARAnnotations)




      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: how do you determine data is not getting passed? Have you set a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: yes, it is set to `nil`.

Comment: please, show code of "Place" class

Comment: see updated question, please.

Comment: Do you have segue between NearMeMapViewController and DetailsViewController in storyboard?

Comment: I don't have a view controller `NearMeMapViewController` . Thats the mistake, maybe?

Comment: Because, the user clicks on a place filter on tableView, it goes to NearMeMapVC and then DetailsVC.

Comment: I just created a view controller and linked to DetailsVC.

Comment: Please, update title bit the code right before self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsVc, animated: true)

let _place = Place(location: (locationManager.location)!, reference: "", name: "", address: "")
print("place need to be passed = \(_place) ")
detailsVc.place = _place
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsVc, animated: true)

Comment: What do you see in logs?

Comment: I see `place need to be passed = (_place) `

Comment: please add back - slash before \ (_place) => print("place need to be passed = \ (_place) ")

Comment: it is showing now `place need to be passed = `

Comment: please check again, print call should look like print("place need to be passed = \ (_place) ") but without whitespace between backslash and (

Comment: same log: also, this is what my storyboard looks like: on the left is nearmeMapVC and on the right is DetailsVC: https://imgur.com/a/b0wMM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update you tapBlurButton func

```
func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if let annotationView = sender.view as? NearMeARAnnotationView {
        if let detailsVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController")
            as? DetailsViewController {

            detailsVc.place = Place(location: (locationManager.location)!,
                                    reference: "",
                                    name: annotationView.annotationNameLabel.text ?? "",
                                    address: annotationView.annotationAddressLabel.text ?? "")
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsVc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Update your NearMeARAnnotationView class

```
class NearMeARAnnotationView: ARAnnotationView, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var annotation: ARAnnotation! //<= ADD this variable.

    //>>Other code here

   init(annotation : ARAnnotation) {
    super .init()
    self.annotation = annotation //<= pass data to your new var
   //>>Other initialization code here
   }
   //>> Other code here
}
```

Update your Details vc code

```
class DetailsViewController: BaseViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
     var annotation: ARAnnotation!
     //>> Other code here
}
```

Update your new tapBlurButton func

```
func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        if let annotationView = sender.view as? NearMeARAnnotationView {
            if let detailsVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController")
                as? DetailsViewController {
                detailsVc.annotation = annotationView.annotation
                detailsVc.place = Place(location: (locationManager.location)!,
                                        reference: "",
                                        name: annotationView.annotationNameLabel.text ?? "",
                                        address: annotationView.annotationAddressLabel.text ?? "")
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsVc, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

An then in your DetailsVC you should be able to access all the data which was in your annotation passed to your NearMeARAnnotationView in this way:

```
let name = annotation.name
let address = annotation.address
```

directly in DetailsVC

Comment: I get this now: `place need to be passed = 
Place is not nil`

Comment: So the place variable is not nil in your details vc!

Comment: Why do you think that it is nil?

Comment: Because earlier I put a breakpoint and it showed me a nil, but now I  can see that now. How can I make the data pass to show the places on DetailVC?

Comment: What data do you need to pass?

Comment: What I have declared in my `Place` object

Comment: You are already passing those data... But I don't understand why you create new Place object and then pass it to Details vc

Comment: So comment `func tapBlurButton` . ?

Comment: No, give me 2 min to figure out what is going on in your view controllers

Comment: Thank you so much. If I want to pass other data I do the same ?

Comment: For instance for phone number: `phoneNumber: annotationView.annotationPhoneLabel.text ??`

Comment: How can we declare the other fields?

Comment: Ok, I will answer you within 10 min

Comment: Please check updated answer. About "If I want to pass other data I do the same ?": If you need to pass some data you need to pass EXACTLY the data you need not a new created empty object.  You had passed empty object, and then you received empty object in your details vc.

Comment: I did. In `detailsVc.place = Place`  for phone number and other fields do I do the same way like `phoneNumberLabel: annotationView.phoneNumberLabel.text ?? ""`

Comment: I haven't seen where you get phoneNumber in your code so I can't answer you exactly. Also I don't see phoneNumberLabel in your NearMeARAnnotationView, so I think you can't do this.

Comment: I'm sorry but I need to get some sleep, hope I helped you. Stay coding, don't give up!

Comment: phoneNumber is in my `Place` class

Comment: Hey @Dmitry did you have a look at my `Place` class that how to show the phoneNumber and the rest of the objects in the DetailVC?

Comment: @HarutSimonyan, I've seen that your Place object contains phone number variable and few other, but I haven't seen where you receive this data. Also you don't pass this data to you Place object during initialization, so you need to think where you can get this data then update Place initialization and make some optimization in your ViewControllers.

Comment: Hey @Dmitry can you help me show my phone Number data, I have declared it and trying to figure out how to get the data for Phone Number?